# Calculating seconds in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, time

I have a code that calculates power consumption of devices in Watts. I need to calculate the KWH usage of that device in that month and i have a formula that looks like this

```
    ( Watt Usage * Hours/Day * Days/Mo. ) / 1000 = Kilowatt Hours used that month
```

I have the Watt Usage,but having trouble with tracking time.So is there a way to calculate seconds so that i can use it to calculate hours,days and unit consumption.

Comment: To calculate seconds you multiply hours by 3600 -- but I suspect you already know that.  I think you need to explain more clearly what your problem is, specifically what time data do you have ?

Comment: Yes you suspected right. I know that time = now returns the current time and then it can be formatted by using date2str(time,'mm/DD HH:MM'); but i want to keep the time the program starts and then subtract it with the current time to see if its an hour.if it is then i can sum up the values of power to see how much power was consumed in that hour...i need to know how to keep track of it..is it as simple as storing the initial time into a variable and keep subtracting it with the current time and simultaneously checking for  the hour condition

Comment: Yes, I think the solution is as you suggest, and is as simple as you state that it is.

Comment: MATLAB datenum values are measured in days.  So multiply by 24 to get hours, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB has some tools for manipulating with time:

**clock**:

```
t=clock; % returns a six-element vector containing the current date and time in decimal form, ( i.e. [year month day hour minute seconds] )
```

**date** :

```
d=date; returns a string containing the date (in dd-mmm-yyyy format).
```

also , you can use **tic** and **toc** to measure elapsed time between two moments.(like a stopwatch)

```
tic;% starts the stopwatch
%  after some time
toc  % returns elapsed time
```